# Python 2.7.5, making loop with unlimited user input, accumulate totals, applying sentinel?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Just started working with an older python book, learning about loops and trying to make a loop that accumulates the user input and then displays the total. The problem is the book only shows how to do this with a range, I want to have the user input as many numbers as they want and then display the total, so for example if the user entered 1,2,3,4 I would need python to output 10, but I don't want to have python tied down to a range of numbers. 
here is the code I have WITH a range, as I stated above, I need to do this user input without being tied down to a range. Also do I need to apply a sentinel for the kind of program I want to make?

```
def main():

    total = 0.0

    print ' this is the accumulator test run '
    for counter in range(5):  #I want the user to be able to enter as many numbers
        number = input('enter a number: ') #as they want. 
        total  = total + number
    print ' the total is', total

main()
```

Comment: have you tried `while True`?

Comment: you are looking for a while loop: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#while .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want a [while-loop](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) here:

```
def main():
    total = 0.0
    print ' this is the accumulator test run '
    # Loop continuously.
    while True:
        # Get the input using raw_input because you are on Python 2.7.
        number = raw_input('enter a number: ')
        # If the user typed in "done"...
        if number == 'done':
            # ...break the loop.
            break
        # Else, try to add the number to the total.
        try:
            # This is the same as total = total + float(number)
            total += float(number)
        # But if it can't (meaning input was not valid)...
        except ValueError:
            # ...continue the loop.
            # You can actually do anything in here.  I just chose to continue.
            continue
    print ' the total is', total
main()
```

Comment: what is the += operator? Why are you using it after the try:?

Comment: @JuanB457 - It is the same as `total = total + float(number)`.  It's just a cleaner way of writing it.

Answer (score 0):

Using your same logic, only replace it with a [`while`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) loop. The loop exits when the user types `0`

```
def main():
    total = 0
    print 'this is the accumulator test run '
    while True:
        number = input('enter a number: ')
        if number == 0:
            break
        total += number
    print 'the total is', total

main()
```

---

Just for fun, here is a one line solution:

```
total = sum(iter(lambda: input('Enter number (or 0 to finish): '), 0))
```

If you want it to display right away:

```
print sum(iter(lambda: input('Enter number (or 0 to finish): '), 0))
```

Comment: @iCodez Well, it actually *does* work, so please check before you make accusations.

Comment: @iCodez:  `input()` works in Python 2.  It interprets the input as arbitrary Python code (unsafe!).

Answer (score 0):

Use a while-loop to loop an indeterminate number of times:

```
total = 0.0
print 'this is the accumulator test run '
while True:
    try:
        # get a string, attempt to cast to float, and add to total
        total += float(raw_input('enter a number: '))
    except ValueError:
        # raw_input() could not be converted to float, so break out of loop
        break
print 'the total is', total
```

A test run:

```
this is the accumulator test run 
enter a number: 12
enter a number: 18.5
enter a number: 3.3333333333333
enter a number: 
the total is 33.8333333333
```